# Dokku view logs? (hosted on digitalocean)

Tags: dokku

So I just started using dokku (with postegres). My app works on Heroku so I'm pretty sure it's a deployment issue. The app seems to be running but is however hitting issues at log in. I did dokku logs my_app_name however the logs seems to be old. On heroku whenever there is an issue there is an corresponding log, but here I cannot find.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get a continuous log you can type:

`dokku logs yourappname -t`

It acts as the *tail -f* command on linux and mac systems.

[Dokku logs - docs](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/logs/)

Answer (score 6):

I think you can try to use `` docker logs -f `cat /home/dokku/<app-name>/CONTAINER `` for getting access to the logs.

In case if you want to see the logs of the specific container:

`docker ps`

then find your container with postgresql for example and run `docker logs -f <CONTAINER_ID>`

I hope it could help you to find out the problem.

Out of the topic I found dokku-alt and using it in my current DO image. If you are working with Ruby it's working out of the box comparing with original dokku project.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest:

```
dokku logs -t *app_name*
```

up to 300000 lines:

```
dokku logs -t -n 300000 *app_name* > logs.txt
```

complete log of container: (needs to be executed on server)

```sh
docker container list # to get the container id
docker logs *container_id* > logs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer you are looking for but I was seeing the same issue. I just waited about 30 seconds and the logs were updated. I don't know why they are updated live, but they eventually came through.